# how to listObjects in Amazon s3 API order by LastModified?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I need to list objects from Amazon s3 in order such that latest uploaded objects should be listed on top ? How it can be done ?

```
$result = $client->listObjects(array(
    // Bucket is required
    'Bucket' => 'string',
    'Delimiter' => 'string',
    'EncodingType' => 'string',
    'Marker' => 'string',
    'MaxKeys' => integer,
    'Prefix' => 'string',
));
```

There is not option to sort it above ?

Below is my code,

```
   $items = $this->get('my.aws_s3.client')->listObjects(array(
        'Bucket' => "my_bucket"
    ));


    foreach ($items as $i) {
        var_dump($i);
    }
```

Below is my output,

```
string 'my_bucket' (length=19)
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
string '1000' (length=4)
boolean true
array (size=1000)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Key' => string '1286319624.tar.gz' (length=26)
      'LastModified' => string '2010-10-05T23:00:50.000Z' (length=24)
      'ETag' => string '"9118de4f6a8e1e21be99d791108eaa57"' (length=34)
      'Size' => string '90460751' (length=8)
      'Owner' => 
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => string '917a9ca91589caf57633aee246d4263777366b4d00aafa9ac3948910f6eb686f' (length=64)
          'DisplayName' => string 'dbrckll' (length=7)
      'StorageClass' => string 'STANDARD' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'Key' => string '1286406023.tar.gz' (length=26)
      'LastModified' => string '2010-10-06T23:00:50.000Z' (length=24)
      'ETag' => string '"e0e94040702eb9e18a906140fb706767"' (length=34)
      'Size' => string '90460758' (length=8)
      'Owner' => 
        array (size=2)
          'ID' => string '917a9ca91589caf57633aee246d4263777366b4d00aafa9ac3948910f6eb686f' (length=64)
          'DisplayName' => string 'dbrckll' (length=7)
      'StorageClass' => string 'STANDARD' (length=8)
  2 =>
```

If you see LastModified 
  'LastModified' => string '2010-10-05T23:00:50.000Z' is displayed first and then
   'LastModified' => string '2010-10-06T23:00:50.000Z'

How do I sort it in descending order of LastModified ?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes, i am getting results but in it shows in ascending order of lastmodiffied date

Comment: Then you should add your own code here first.

Comment: There is not much to add as it is just an api call, I have added above.

Comment: You can do it manually. Getting no reference in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

[There](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-iterators.html) is a suggestion to use the Spl Iterators, so it actually depends on your implementation unfortunately. Here is my implementation using the iterators:

```
    $iterator = $client->getListObjectsIterator([
        'Bucket' => 'string',
        'Prefix' => 'string',
        'MAX' => 1000,
    ]);

    $arrayIterator = new \ArrayIterator($iterator->toArray());
    $arrayIterator->uasort(function($a, $b){
        $itemADate = (new DateTime($a['LastModified']));
        $itemBDate = (new DateTime($b['LastModified']));

        return $itemADate->diffInSeconds($itemBDate, false) > 0;
    });
```

*DateTime is just a [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) implementation

Answer (score 0):

since this is an older s3 variant I now use this

```
$objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [
    'Bucket' => 'string',
    'Prefix' => 'string'
]);
$Iterator = new \ArrayIterator($objects);
$Iterator->uasort(function($a, $b){
    $aDate = (new DateTime($a['LastModified']));
    $bDate = (new DateTime($b['LastModified']));

    return $aDate->diffInSeconds($bDate, false) > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, I want to show s3 data on a table with descending order of Last Modified. After several experiments, I have found this solution and it works for me.
As per my research, there are no any attributes for sorting in **$s3Client->listObjects** function, so I have done via custom code as follows.

```
    $response = $s3Client->listObjects(array('Bucket' => $bucket, 'MaxKeys' => 1000));
    $files = $response->getPath('Contents');

    if(!empty($files)) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file['Key'];
            $file_path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

            $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $file_name = $file_path_parts['filename'].'.'.$ext;
            if($ext == '') {
                $ext = 'folder';
                $file_name = $file_path_parts['filename'];
            }
            $fileArray = array(
                            'name' => $file_name,
                            'file_type' => $ext,
                            'key_file' => $file['Key'],
                            'time' => $file['LastModified']->format(\DateTime::ISO8601),
                            'download_link' => $link.$file_name,
                            'size' => convert_filesize($file['Size'],2)
            );
            $responseFromBucket[] = $fileArray;
        }
    }

    //Short By Desc
    $key_values = array_column($responseFromBucket, 'time'); 
    array_multisort($key_values, SORT_DESC, $responseFromBucket);
```

In my code, I have pushed required data to an array then simply I performed array multisort with the array.